# OOPS Concept Abstract and final

Tags: php, oop

can we create a final method in abstract class ?

can we create a abstract method in final class ?

pls give me explanation with coding.

Thanks advance for your answer.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: @David it seems doing google is harder than posting a question here.

Comment: @David : i didn't try that. i want to know the concept, there after i will apply as per my need.

Comment: can we create the final method in abstract class . yes we can . see the below code for further reference /* final method in abstract class */
abstract class base {
    public $name;
    abstract public function getName();
    
    final public function setName($inputName) {
        $this->name = $inputName;
    }
}

class child extends base {
    
    public function getName() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}

$obj = new child();
$obj->setName('Software Engineer');
$obj->getName();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) can we create the final method in abstract class .
 yes we can .
 see the below code for further reference                                                                    /* final method in abstract class */
abstract class base {
    public $name;
    abstract public function getName();

    final public function setName($inputName) {
        $this->name = $inputName;
    }
}

class child extends base {

    public function getName() {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}



$obj = new child();
$obj->setName('Software Engineer');
$obj->getName();                          
2 . can we create a abstract method in final class ?                                                                                                                   No. we can not create the abstract method in final class,
```

Answer (score 1):

No Not do like this .

```
   class PersonalLoan{
     public final String getName(){
         return "personal loan";
     }
    }
    class CheapPersonalLoan extends PersonalLoan{
        @Override
        public final String getName(){
            return "cheap personal loan"; //compilation error: overridden method is final
        }
    }
```

but  abstract class  having  abstract method .   abstract method must be define in inherit function so it not

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can.
2. No, you can't. You can only declare an abstract method in an abstract class. See the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) for more informations.

Comment: can you give me some other example link to understand about my questions.